# Trigger on date in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm reading a lot of articles how to create triggers, but I really have no clue how to create trigger depending on date.

I want to add a trigger that:
1. check before add or update if the sum of minutes is higher than 50 on a specific day.

So in example entity:

```
CREATE TABLE employees(
   id int serial primary key,
   minutes int NOT NULL,
   date date NOT NULL
);
```

this is a typical data in db:

```
(1, 40, '2018-01-1')
(2, 30, '2018-01-2')
(3, 20, '2018-01-3')
(4, 10, '2018-01-4')
```

now if I add:

```
(6, 20, '2018-01-1')
(7, 40, '2018-01-2')
(8, 20, '2018-01-3')
(9, 20, '2018-01-4')
```

the final result would've be:

```
(1, 40, '2018-01-1')
(2, 30, '2018-01-2')
(3, 20, '2018-01-3')
(4, 10, '2018-01-4')
(8, 20, '2018-01-3')
(9, 20, '2018-01-4')
```

id with 6 and 7 are omitted (not added, because they are higher than 50)

I really appreciate a help with it :)

update: with help from @Laurenz Albe I created function and trigger as below:

```
        CREATE FUNCTION func_check_minutes() RETURNS trigger AS
        $$
        BEGIN
        IF (SELECT sum(minutes) + NEW.minutes FROM employees WHERE date = NEW.date) > 50
        THEN RETURN NULL;
        END IF;
        END;
        $$
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

        CREATE TRIGGER tr_check_minutes
        BEFORE INSERT ON employees
        FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_check_minutes();
```

But this solution fails without a clear reason.

Comment: "Fails" is not enough. Show an error message.

Comment: Reason: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the trigger, it is from your Java code. Try directly on the database with psql.

Comment: good idea, let me check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not mentioned what fails, i am assuming that nothing is being written to the table. You will have to add `RETURN NEW` after the `END IF`

I have updated the trigger

```
CREATE FUNCTION func_check_minutes() RETURNS trigger AS
        $$
        BEGIN
        IF (SELECT sum(minutes) + NEW.minutes FROM employees WHERE date = NEW.date) > 50
        THEN RETURN NULL;
        END IF;

        RETURN NEW;

        END;
        $$
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

        CREATE TRIGGER tr_check_minutes
        BEFORE INSERT ON employees
        FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_check_minutes();
```

Comment: and truelly this can be solution (let me check it and I'll write progress soon)

Answer (score 1):

The central piece of such a trigger would be:

```
IF (SELECT sum(minutes) + NEW.minutes
    FROM employees
    WHERE date = NEW.date) > 50
THEN
   <throw an error or return NULL>
END IF;
```

But you should be aware that there is a race condition that could cause the condition to be violated:

If the triggers from two inserts run concurrently, each of them won't see the effects of the other transaction, and both could report success while the final result after both transactions are committed could exceed the limit.

The only way to get around that would be using `SERIALIZABLE` transactions.